What kind of MOSFET is this?
I'm trying to identify Q1 in this photo. It's a type of MOSFET it is and what kind of symbol I'd use for it in KiCAD. It's from the website:
https://www.pololu.com/product/2130



The MOSFET is a 20V ~3A p-channel enhancement mode MOSFET made by Diodes Incorporated P/N DMP2305U-7 or a compatible with similar markings.


P-channel enhancement mode, more than that we can't say. Without values for VIN, D1, or load current we can't even recommend something that would work in this application. (Edit: this answer was posted before the source of the schematic was edited into the question; see Spehro's answer for the specific device referenced.)

Thanks! I was just wondering about the type of MOSFET used and what it would be called in KiCAD.

Note that this reverse polarity protection application has the MOSFET "backwards" with current flowing from drain to source. Normal current flow is the opposite direction (for P-channel), but the body diode must be oriented this way for the circuit to work correctly. Performance may not match datasheet figures in this case.
